# DotCover not working

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I am using `DotCoverNUnit` in FAKE for code coverage .
It is giving some error

```
`Starting Target: TestCoverage (==> BuildUnitTest)
./Buildtools/dotCover/dotCover.exe "cover" "/TargetExecutable=./Libs/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/nunit-console.exe" "/TargetArguments="-nologo" "-labels" "D:\Project\build\project.UnitTest.dll" "-xml:D:\Project\TestResult.xml"" "/Output=./test/NUnitDotCover.xml"
./Buildtools/dotCover/dotCover.exe "cover" "/TargetExecutable=./Libs/NUnit.Runners.2.6.3/tools/nunit-console.exe" "/TargetArguments="-nologo" "-labels" "D:\Project\build\Project.UnitTest.dll" "-xml:D:\Project\TestResult.xml"" "/Output=./test/NUnitDotCover.xml"
JetBrains dotCover Console Runner v2.6.608.684. Copyright (c) 2009–2017 JetBrains s.r.o. All rights reserved.
**Command 'cover' doesn't support 4 unnamed arguments**
Type 'dotCover help' for usage.
Running build failed.
Error:
System.Exception: Error running ./Buildtools/dotCover/dotCover.exe with exitcode -1
   at Fake.DotCover.buildParamsAndExecute@124-6.Invoke(String message)
   at Fake.DotCover.buildParamsAndExecute[a](a parameters, FSharpFunc2 buildArguments,String toolPath, String workingDir, Boolean failBuild)
   at Fake.DotCover.DotCoverNUnit(FSharpFunc 2 setDotCoverParams, FSharpFunc2 setNUnitParams, IEnumerable 1 assemblies)
   at FSI_0005.Build.clo@98-8.Invoke(Unit _arg6) in D:\ICIS API develop\icis-api\build.fsx:line 99`
```

I am not able to figure out the problem out there in this code , I was able to run this code earlier but right now it is not wroking .

Here is the code that I am using for DotCover :

```
Target "TestCoverage" (fun _ ->
!! (buildDir @@ "/Project.UnitTest.dll")
    |> DotCoverNUnit
        (fun p -> { p with TargetExecutable ="nunit-console.exe"
                           Output ="NUnitDotCover.xml"
                           ToolPath = "dotCover.exe"                                                           
                           ErrorLevel = DontFailBuild
                           Filters = filters })
        (fun nunitOptions ->
             { nunitOptions with DisableShadowCopy = true })
tracefn "##teamcity[importData type='dotNetCoverage' tool='dotcover' path='%s']" (testDir @@ "NUnitDotCover.xml")
```

)

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with those tools, but the command line (as shown in the diagnostics) looks to have a conflict between quotes around the whole ``/TargetArguments`` section and the ``-nologo`` ``-labels`` etc within it. Is that anything you have control over?

Comment: there is error : `Command 'cover' doesn't support 4 unnamed arguments` I don't get this .

Comment: I think the quote that's intended to open around ``-nologo`` actually closes the quotes around ``/TargetArguments=``, so then ``nologo``, ``labels``, ``D:...`` and ``xml...`` get passed as arguments to dotcover instead of nunit, and dotcover doesn't know what to do with them.

Comment: yes , but `TargetArguments` is optional .

Comment: It looks like it's being filled out for you, but looks to be wrong.

Comment: I had similar problems with OpenCover not liking paths with spaces.  I solved it by using Directory.EnumerateFiles instead of FAKE's "!!" operator.